# Button is not found in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

All I'm working on a small game using node js, so I have a button and when I press the button a rectangle should be drawn in the canvas that is present on my Html page.

But I think my node js is loading faster than my Html, how can I make all my Html elements load and then node js execute.

Here is my code

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sanke Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="submit" id = "smallButton" name="button">Draw</button>
    <canvas id="canvas" tabindex="0" width="640" height="480"></canvas>



  <script src="userInput.js"></script>
  <script src="snake.js"></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="client.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

snake.js

```
const gameBoard = document.getElementById("canvas");
const gameBoard_ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const bun = document.getElementById("smallButton");


//Generating Random Coordinate
function randomCoordinates(){
  var startX = 40+Math.random()*560;
  var startY = 40+Math.random()*400;
  return [startX, startY];
}


// Drawing snake
function drawSnakePart(snakePart){
  gameBoard_ctx.fillStyle = 'lightblue';
  gameBoard_ctx.strokestyle = 'darkblue';
  gameBoard_ctx.fillRect(snakePart[0], snakePart[1], 10, 10);
  gameBoard_ctx.strokeRect(snakePart[0], snakePart[1], 10, 10)
}

function drawSnake(){
  for(var i=0; i<8; i++){
    drawSnakePart(randomCoordinates());
  }
}


bun.addEventListener("click", function(){
  alert("clicked");
  drawSnake();
})
```

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");


const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

//Responding to Root request
app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
})



//Responds if client request is made
app.get("/client.js", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/client.js");
})

//Responds to css req
app.get("/styles.css", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/styles.css");
})

//Responds to keyMovements
app.get("/userInput.js", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname+"/userInput.js");
})

 app.get("/snake.js", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname+"/snake.js");
 })





io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log("User is connected");
  socket.on("disconnect", function(){
    console.log("User Disconnected");
  })
  socket.emit("serverToClient", "Hello World");
  socket.on("clientToServer", function(event){
    console.log(event);
  })

  socket.on("clientToClient", data => {
    socket.broadcast.emit("serverToClient", data);
  })
})


server.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Listening to port 3000");
})
```

Comment: *"But i think my node js is loading faster than my html"* - What exactly do you mean by that?  NodeJS code is running server-side, and HTML is rendered by the browser client-side.  They execute at two entirely different times in two entirely different contexts.  What is the actual problem you're observing?

Comment: nodeJS executes server-side, so it won't execute after your HTML unless you make an AJAX request or websocket connection to it from the client-side, which I don't see any evidence of from what you've posted (although admittedly there's clearly some JS you haven't posted). Are you actually talking about your client-side JavaScript code? What _exact_ problem are you seeing? And make sure what you've posted is actually a [mre] of your issue.

Comment: I'd assume the issue is somehow related to the socket, but there's nothing in the client-side code handling the socket connection.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.